# Using Swiffy html5 banners in Adwords

Tags: html, google-ads-api, google-swiffy

I've successfully used swiffy to convert a flash banner to html5 - to be used on Adwords

However I keep running into hurdles for uploading them -

the first issue was the swiffy file didnt include the meta ad size property - easy enough to fix

second issue is - swiffy files point to an external runtime.js, and Adwords requires all files to be local.  runtime.js is HUGE and will easily put me over the 150kb size limit when zipped.

third issue (once i'm able to find a way around the runtime.js issue) would be having the ad server clickTag function like a swf banner - and not be set static in the file

has ANYone- successfully served an html5 banner on Adwords made via swiffy?

Answer (score 0):

We did, but the size was the biggest problem. Did you manage to get the runtime.js down to anything usable. We were lucky with some banners which were small to begin with. The clicktag works seamlessly once you upload the .zip, GDN takes care of that.

Comment: Our google rep basically told us to give up on swiffy and just rebuild it in google web designer -

our banners work fine in GWD, however the animation pales in comparison to what you can do in flash :/

Answer (score 0):

Ive built over 100 banners in Swiffy and all have trafficked just fine in DCS, DCM, Sizmek and 3rd party. I have not done any Adwords banners yet, but my DCM rep told me that adwords can auto convert SWF ads into Swiffy. I am not sure how that works and I have not done that yet. Also, I have been told by reps in Sizmek, DCM and DCS that runtime.js is NOT counted in the file size when you put it in externally since most browsers will be caching that file. So the user would be caching that file after they viewed 1 banner and after that it would only be downloading the Swiffy ad.

For the clicktags, we have been using this successfully:

```
CODE FOR THE FLA FILE...... Make sure you remove the old clicktags and replace it with this for each clicktag. Modify the movieclip name as needed.....





import flash.external.*;


//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\
// ----- CLICK THROUGH ----- \\


mybackgroundclick.onRelease = function():Void{
    ExternalInterface.call("bannerBgClicked")
};


//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\





CODE FOR THE HTML FILE...... This goes inside the <HEAD> section, but put it at the very end, just before </HEAD>......


<script type="text/javascript"> var clickTag = "http://www.google.com"; </script>
    <script>
     function bannerBgClicked(){
        window.open(window.clickTag);
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

For Clicktag this seems fit in most cases with Swiffy content.
Add to head:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var clickTag = "%c";
</script>
```

Add this to body just after the `div id="swiffycontainer"` element at bottom of document code (before closing /body tag):

```
<a onclick="window.open(window.clickTag, '_blank')" style="cursor:pointer; text-decoration:none;">
  <div style="width:160px; height:600px; left:0px; top:0px; position:absolute;"></div>
</a>
```

Change the 'height' and 'width' properties to the proper size of document.

Comment: Sorry comment got a bit missed up here it seems. Jist is add script with clickTag variable to head of doc and the formatted a tag before closing... /